# Templating with anonymous functions and usage of output buffer in PHP

Tags: php, anonymous-function, output-buffering

I figure I'd better ask than make a fool of myself some time when I get my code reviewed.

I am making a website, trying to follow MVC design architecture, although it might not even be MVC but I figured it works nice.

Currently, I am doing something like this;

I have a render() function that takes a string $template and array of arguments,

```
render($template, $vars=[]){
    extract($vars);
    ob_start();
    include($template.'.php');
    ob_flush();
}
```

and outputs the view. In a controller, I then do this,

```
Class WhicheverController

    public static function defaultAction(){
        $article=Article::getOneByID(array('id'=>$_GET['id'], 'user'=>User::currentUser()));  //returns database result as object
        render('_header', array('title'=>$article->title));
        render('header', array('user'=>User::currentUser()));
        render('sidebar', array('user'=>User::currentUser()));
        $content=Comment::getByArticleID(array('article'=>$article->id));  //returns object
        //of root comments, highest level in comment-replies tree
        $comments=function() use ($content){
            foreach($content as $comment){
                $threads[]=function() use ($comment){
                    render('comment', array('comment'=>$comment));
                }
            }
            render('pagination', array('content'=>$threads)); //pagination paginates based on number of
            //items in content, and echoes it or runs it if it is_callable
        }
        render('article', array('article'=>$article, 'comments'=>$comments));
    }
```

And finally in article.php;

```
//some html with echoing $article->variablethis or variablethat
<div class="comments">
    <?= $comments(); ?>
</div>
```

Now, the way I figured it out, ob_flush() sends to client prematurely, so I get headers with styles and header and sidebar printed as I am getting the neccessary variables. That is good (if that's how it works).

Then, I want to do the same with the main content - article and comments. First I get the comments and article data, and pass it to article.php. But I have to do some pagination logic first before sending it away, and that would delay rendering of article.php. So I create an anonymous function which does that, and pass that as a variable function $comments(); which does it's logic when it is called.

This is only one example. In one controller I first get top rated articles of today, yesterday and current week, and create anonymous function for each one, before passing it to frontpage.php. Frontpage.php does this, essentialy;

```
//some html markup
<?= $articles24h(); ?>
//more html
<?= $articles48h(); ?>
//and so on
```

Now, when I thought of this I thought it was brilliant but as I started to add more variable functions I noticed my code was starting to become longer and I presume anyone other than me illegible.

My question is: is this bad practice; this usage of anonymous functions, variable functions and ob_flush() (more importanntly, does it do what I think it does)?

EDIT: The code itself works. In here I might've made some logical mistakes, but the point is to display the usage of functions.

EDIT 2: <strike>Okay, so I realized I can have one anonymous function display <strike>`$articles24h` and `$articles48h`</strike> any paginating content just by passing each as `$content`, like so `function($content) use ($something_else, $but_common){ //yada yada }`, which helps a lot, but I still don't know if this is desirable. i.e. there is a better way.</strike>

EDIT 3: I created 3 View classes, one View class with static render() method that just takes a template name and array with variables and prints out a template, and two others, PaginationView and PartialView; both have their own render() method and don't extend View class (even thought if I was a better programmer yadda yadda I' do it differently). Pagination paginates partial views that PartialView stores in a class variable and creats when constructed. If I don't need to paginate data, I just call `PartialView->render()`

Neat (IMO), but it looks kinda ugly in code, like so:

```
$content=Article::getByAuthorID(array('author'=>$profile->id), array('order'=>$order,'column'=>'time_submitted'));
$user_articles=new PartialView('_article', $content, array('length'=>60));
$user_articles=new PaginationView($user_articles->views, 10, 1);
```

`$user_articles` is then sent to

```
echo View::render('user_page', array('articles'=>$user_articles, 'profile'=>$profile, 'comments'=>$user_comments));
```

As you can see, I also do this for comments so the code gets lengthy. I don't want to change anything it I am not breaking anything, although I feel like this is a violation of DRY in some way (?)

Is there a better way to do this, without sacrificing clarity but making it more compact?

Comment: instead of `ob_flush()` use `return ob_get_clean()`, you be able to store and build your output. the render function should also not be global, it should be part of your view class.

Comment: @Lawrence So for each view, I'd do, say, $sidebar=new View();, building variables like $sidebar->user, and rendering like $sidebar->render('sidebar'); ?

Comment: create base class for controllers define method lets say `getComponent` which will then call lets say `createComponentPagination` which will be defined in `WhicheverController`, define pagination as component, with its own render function, make templates as function and pass controller itself to them, then you could call something like this in template: `$controller->getComponent('pagination')->render()`

Comment: @Kazz I defined a new `PaginationView` that takes model data and renders it. Problem is, sometimes (actually, most of the time) I need to prerender the data to pass additional variables to it, so I also created PartialView which takes content, template file and variables and returns an array with partial views that I want to paginate. It does seem cleaner now but I have to do `$something=new PartialView` and then `$articles = new PaginationView($something, ... )`, which still looks ugly. The code is functional as it is, but I want it cleaner. Is this a case of premature optimization?